# ASP.NET Websocket behavior on Pool recycle

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, websocket

I'm currently evaluating using asp.net websockets for connecting a few thousands clients that will stay connected with the app pretty much 24x7, except for when the server goes offline for patching etc. Generally, the expectation from the system is that websockets should not disconnect unnecessarily and the clients will basically stay connected and ping the server every few mins.

While I was researching asp.net websocket viability for our new architecture, I came across another stackoverflow post: [IIS App Pool cannot recycle when there is an open ASP.NET 4.5 Websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397484/iis-app-pool-cannot-recycle-when-there-is-an-open-asp-net-4-5-websocket) which seems to suggest that IIS doesn't recycle the pool if there is an active websocket connection. Is this by design or did the other person experience an anomaly? If IIS does recycle the pool while the websocket connections are active, what's the expected behavior? Does Http.sys keep the connections, recycles the pool and things resume as if nothing happened (from the client's perspective)? Should I just create a separate app pool for websockets and disable recycling on it?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience no, the WebSockets on the old worker process are not transitioned to the new worker process. I have observed that the old WebSockets are put into a non-Open state and it is up to your code to check this and stop maintaining those threads - my application was creating a heartbeat to the client over WebSockets and if the heartbeat failed I needed to close that (already closed) WebSocket context as soon as possible so the old worker process could fully unload and die.